# Problems installing Ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to to istall ubuntu (desktop 14.4) on my computer running
windows 10 home (as dual operating system).  I have an empty 100 gb partition
on the disk; do I have to format it first.

Comment: Why does it matter to you to format or not to format If it's empty ?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If pre-installed Windows then it will be UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 8 screens or similar to Windows 10
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu installer will format it.

Make sure you have read the [installation guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) before you start.